# kubernetes output using custom columns

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get results with nodes having certain role using `kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns`

```
kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=ROLE:.metadata.labels.node-role.kubernetes.io/ingress
```

But then I would get no result regardless of having nodes with ingress role.

I feel like when I'm using this command

```
kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=ROLE:.metadata.labels.node-role.kubernetes.io/ingress
```

"." is the delimiter and that's why it won't show any results.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in this question: [kubectl: Use custom-columns output with maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418535/kubectl-use-custom-columns-output-with-maps)

try `kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=ROLE:".metadata.labels.node-role\.kubernetes\.io/ingress"`